# Launch a Separate exe from within JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-8, javafx-2, exe, media

**Preface**: I'm very new to JavaFX and programming in general so I kindly ask that you provide as lay an answer as possible when responding.

With that said, I am creating a JavaFX program where a user selects a number of media files (using FileChooser), those files are stored in a ListView, and the user then has the option to launch those files using a different program (i.e. a media player).

So, what I am looking for is two things:
A) How do you launch a program (e.g. VLC) from within JavaFX.
B) How do you send a list of files for that program to load within its playlist?

For A, I would be using a button to launch the program, but I think I can figure out how to tie the method with the button. I'm basically looking for any Java classes that I can learn about that will handle the work of launching an exe.

For B, I understand that the response might vary from program to program (VLC one process, WMP another), and if that's the case, either an abstract implementation suggestion, or how to specifically load a playlist into VLC itself should be of great help!

I haven't included any source code since I couldn't find any answers online and don't have anything at all WRT these two processes but if it's needed, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So, I found a solution after I realized that I might have better luck searching the problem with "Java" instead of "JavaFX" explicitly.

I'm posting here for anyone who may come upon a similar problem in the future.

The Java class that can be used to load an external exe/software/process is the ProcessBuilder class. You can read more about that class [HERE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

The code:

```
        Process process = new ProcessBuilder("the absolute path of the exe here", 
filesToString).start();
```

Normally, the second (and further) argument(s) would be absolute path(s) of the file(s) that the exe should load.

In my case, since the user determines the amount of files, I couldn't know how many files would be loaded, let alone the name of the absolute path(s), and therefore couldn't predict how many (or what) argument(s) to pass. The way I solved this was to convert all of the user selected files from an ArrayList to  a string, and use replaceAll to create comma separated files within the single string.

The code below might be self-explanitory.

```
//this actually needs to be done before the process above
        filesToString = randomizedFiles.toString().replaceAll(", ", "\" \"").replaceAll("\\[", "\"").replaceAll("\\]", "\"");
```

And voila, that took care of the issue.